# Pattern Matching Error in Python Using Pandas.series.str.contains for String Replacement

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, replace, pattern-matching

I am attempting to replace a string within a pandas dataframe, with a string pulled from a dictionary which contains multiple sets of parentheses. When running the script, I get an error for match groups, and the string is not replaced. I'm fairly confident that this error is caused by the parentheses.

To resolve, I have been attempting to use regular expression pattern matching using the str.contains() method. I have reviewed other solutions provided on stackoverflow, but haven't been successful in resolving my error.

Here is some script I am using for testing purposes. It's important that the parentheses are maintained in the strings (i.e. I don't to have to remove them):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict= {'2017() (pat)':'2000',
       '2018() (pat)':'2001'}

df = pd.DataFrame({'YEAR': ['test2017end','test2018end','test2019end'],
                   'MONTH': ['Jan','Feb','Mar'],
                   'DD': ['1','12','22']})

for init, repl in dict.items():
    df.loc[df['YEAR'].str.contains(init),'YEAR'] = repl

print(df)
```

Can someone please provide guidance on using pattern matching so that the strings are properly replaced?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't name dictionaries `dict`

Answer (score 1):

Dont use variable `dict`, because python code keyword.

Solution is extract first integer in key of dictionary:

```
import re

d= {'2017() (pat)':'2000',
       '2018() (pat)':'2001'}

df = pd.DataFrame({'YEAR': ['test2017end','test2018end','test2019end'],
                   'MONTH': ['Jan','Feb','Mar'],
                   'DD': ['1','12','22']})

for init, repl in d.items():
    i = re.findall('\d+', init)[0]
    df.loc[df['YEAR'].str.contains(i),'YEAR'] = repl

print(df)
          YEAR MONTH  DD
0         2000   Jan   1
1         2001   Feb  12
2  test2019end   Mar  22
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried methods that doesn’t involve looping? Something in this direction:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

dict_= {'2017() (pat)':'2000',
       '2018() (pat)':'2001'}

df = pd.DataFrame({'YEAR': ['test2017end','test2018end','test2019end'],
                   'MONTH': ['Jan','Feb','Mar'],
                   'DD': ['1','12','22']})

pat = r'(\d{4,4})'

dict_b = {re.search(pat, key).group(1):item for key, item in dict_.items()}

# Return NaN for no match
df['YEARX'] = df['YEAR'].str.extract(pat,expand=False).map(dict_b)

# Return found year for no match
df['YEARY'] = df['YEAR'].str.extract(pat,
                  expand=False).apply(lambda x: dict_b[x] if x in dict_b.keys() else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the quick responses. My code was a little more complicated than I posted, and I was actually matching characters rather than numbers. I modified jerzael's response for this and the script functions correctly. Here is my test script I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

dct= {'love (one)()':'john',
       'smith (two)()':'doe',
       'ken (three)()':'yearns'}

df = pd.DataFrame({'MAN': ['test|smith (two)()end','test|love (one)()end','test|ken (three)()end'],
                   'MONTH': ['Jan','Feb','Mar'],
                   'DD': ['1','12','22']})

for init, repl in dct.items():
    i = re.findall(r'\w+', init)[0]
    df.loc[df['MAN'].str.contains(i),'MAN'] = repl

print(df)
```

For the beginners like me, the regular expression how to documentation is a must (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto)

Cheers